# How can I capture an Internet Radio Stream using Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows, streaming, vlc-media-player, windows-media-player

I have an internet radio stream that I need to capture: http://www2.mcot.net/radio/fm_1005.asx

For some reason I cannot open in using VLC Media Player.

But it opens just fine in Windows Media Player.

Is there a way to capture an internet radio stream using Windows Media Player?

Comment: Hi @Vaccano - remember, it's *VLC* and not *VCL* - this will help index your questions properly and for VLC fans and experts to find them! I'll do you an edit.

Comment: @linker3000- Duh! <Palm to Forehead>. Sorry I did not get that when you told me on my other question...  Thanks for the correction.  I will get that right for future questions.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Replay Media Catcher](http://www.replaymediacatcher.org) in the past, although that's commercial; try [free alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/replay-media-catcher/).

> For those of you who don’t know, Replay Media Catcher is one of the fastest growing programs for recording and downloading music and video files to the computer. It was released several years ago and it is currently on it’s 4th version at the time of this writing.
>
> [image]

Just hit the record button and then go to stream your favorite thing in your favorite software.

Answer (score 0):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) should do the trick nicely

Comment: You need to have "Stereo Mix" as a recording device to use Audacity.  Sadly, I do not.  I guess I could get a cable and link my headphones out to my line in... but I was hoping for a non-harware solution...

Comment: Hi, let us know, which OS do you use. In Win7 there is a trick to get the Stereo Mix working.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.